# After setting up a smart TV, phone and laptop only connect to the internet after opening the router admin page

Tags: wireless-networking, smart-tv

Our WiFi is ok. But after some time, if I disconnect it from my Android phone and try to reconnect it, it is stuck on obtaining the IP address but doesn't connect. On my laptop, it connects but shows no internet, even though my WiFi has internet. When I open the router admin page on the laptop, the phone connects immediately and the laptop gets WiFi connected.

Every time, I need to go to the router admin page just to trigger the connection to connect my phone and else. This problem has been happening since I bought a smart TV a week ago. I connected the TV with my WiFi, so from then, whenever I turned off the TV, after some time, all other devices stuck to obtaining the IP address if not connected before turning off the TV. But when I turn the TV on, the device connects immediately and gets internet.

It's very painful to go to the router admin page or to turn on the TV just to connect to WiFi on the phone or other devices. Note that when the TV is on and using WiFi, other devices connect to WiFi then no problem occurs. It only happens when I turn off the TV.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two possible solutions that don't require tinkering with the Wi-Fi hub:

- Return the TV as defective. A Wi-Fi device should not be able to upset the functioning of other Wi-Fi devices like this.
- If you don't want to do that, it may be that this TV is not intended to be turned off. Does it have a standby mode that doesn't cause these problems?

Comment: i don't think there is a standby mode, it's just normal smart tv. And even if i return the tv, the problem still  remains unsolve cause it happens even when the tv is off whole day, if i turn my wifi off, and after sometimes turn on again, it stuck to obtaining ip address. i just can't figure out what to do in this situation